# limit choices with dropdown in flask-admin

Tags: python, flask-admin

My SQLAlchemy model has a `String` field that I would like to limit to a few choices.

I am wondering how I would be able to create a dropdown for this field in the Flask-Admin interface that would ensure that the db is only populated with one of my choices. If I let the user manually enter these fields, they may spell them incorrectly, etc.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

## `enum`, `form_choices` and `form_args`

Your question is about restricting values at the form level, but we can also briefly discuss it at the schema level.

**A. Restricting Values at the Database Level: `enum` fields**

To limit the range of allowable values, the first thing to consider is whether you might like the database to enforce that for you. Most databases have an `enum` type field that allow you to restrict a field to a set of values ([MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/enum.html), [PostGres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-enum.html)). This approach has pros and cons. Among the cons, the values may not be listed in the order you expect; and each time you want to introduce new values to the set, you have to modify the database.

**B. Restricting Values with drop-downs: `form_choices`**

To create drop-downs that present a set of allowable values, create a customized ModelView and define your range of values in `form_choices`. For instance:

```
class FilmAdmin(sqla.ModelView):

    form_choices = { 'now_showing': [ ('0', 'Not Showing'), ('1', 'Showing')],
                     'color': [('bw', 'Black & White'), ('color', 'Color')]
                   }

    # (many other customizations can go here)
```

In `form_choices`, you have created drop-downs for two fields: `now_showing` and `color`. The first field admits the values `0` and `1`, but to make it easier on the eyes the form will show *Not Showing* for `0` and *Showing* for `1`.

Note that this will work in a regular form, but not in an *inline form*.

You will need to add the ModelView to the app: something like

`admin.add_view(FilmAdmin(yourmodels.Film, db.session))`

**C. Validation: `form_args`**

In inline forms, you may not have the drop-down. But you can keep refining your custom ModelView by defining WTF validators for various fields.

As we did with `form_choices`, you can define a `form_args` dictionary containing a `validators` list. For instance:

```
# first import the `AnyOf` validator: 
from wtforms.validators import AnyOf

class FilmAdmin(sqla.ModelView):

    # column_exclude_list = ...
    # form_excluded_columns = ...
    # form_choices = ...

    form_args = {
        'flavors': {
            'validators': [AnyOf(['strawberry', 'chocolate'])]
        }
    }
```

There are many pre-defined validators, and you can define your own: please refer to the [flask-admin introduction](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/introduction/) and to the [validators section of the WTF documentation](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6.1/validators.html).

Comment: Choice "A" was originally used, although it creates a multitude of nightmares (as you mentioned). So, I modified it to a string field and restrict the entries in the controllers.

Comment: Yeah, there's a time and place for `enum`. Storage is smaller with `enum` (only one copy of the value), but lookup / joining can be slower (discussed on pp.123-124 of *High-Performance MySQL*, 3rd ed. It's a good question, hope it will be helpful to others. :)

Comment: By the way there seems to be a [bug with `enum` fields in flask-admin](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/issues/1003) which may be what you were experiencing. At the moment flask-admin seems to have a lot of [unresolved issues which are not so minor](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/issues) (see the Security thing #1000 and others). You'd think that by 2015 the problem of creating admin interfaces would be solved, but not at all. I haven't found the silver bullet apart from taking the time to code the whole thing by hand, which also lets me avoid the terribly inefficient ORM

Comment: use form_choices and column_choices together, would be better